# ID.length doesnt return the expected value

Tags: javascript, html

i have 3 checkbox with same ID. When I try to do following in the javascript I get the output as 9. Can you see where am I going wrong?

onclick of checkbox; I calling a function --> chkBoxCount(this);

```
function chkBoxCount(chk){
   alert(chk.id.length;}
```

EDIT:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="f_seizure" id="f_seizure_1" onclick="chkBoxCount(this);" value="0"> No known episode
                        <input type="checkbox" name="f_seizure" id="f_seizure_2" onclick="chkBoxCount(this);" value="1"> EEG
                        <input type="checkbox" name="f_seizure" id="f_seizure_3" onclick="chkBoxCount(this);" value="2"> Suspected/Clinical
```

Comment: `id` has to be unique, you can't have three elements with the same identifier.

Comment: I tried with name also, it gives me the same result.

Comment: show your HTML and where you invoke the "chkBoxCount(...)" method, also does that even work... it seems you're missing the right ")" parentheses of the alert method.

Comment: I've tested it, works fine for me.

Comment: Added the html for checkbox in the post.

Comment: Post the whole code of `chkBoxCount`!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir he has.

Comment: Okey you have added your html, but now what? It works fine... It returns the length of `id` attribute of each element.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw he didn't! I meant JS code of the function!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir what's this --> function chkBoxCount(chk){
   alert(chk.id.length) ; }  ???? this is his function.

Comment: function chkBoxCount(chk){
   alert(chk.name.length;}

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw well if that is all the code then there is nothing wrong with it!

Comment: i get 9 instead of 3.

Comment: To use length attribute, it has to be in an array. First separate the letters into an array to count them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that you expected 3 as result, so if i'm understanding, you want to count the number of checkboxes with the same name. This is how to do it, enjoy ^^

```js
chkBoxCount = function() {
  alert($("input[name=f_seizure]").length);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="f_seizure" id="f_seizure_1" onclick="chkBoxCount();" value="0"> No known episode
                        <input type="checkbox" name="f_seizure" id="f_seizure_2" onclick="chkBoxCount();" value="1"> EEG
                        <input type="checkbox" name="f_seizure" id="f_seizure_3" onclick="chkBoxCount();" value="2"> Suspected/Clinical
```

Comment: thanks! I used getElmentsbyname(). And it worked. I taught me a new way. This will be helpful somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" id="bike" onclick="chkBoxCount(this)" > I have a bike</input>

function chkBoxCount(chk){
var id = chk.id;
id = id.split(""); 
alert(id.length);
}
```

What this does is get the passed element's id, substring it into indivual characters, and then alert the number of characters. This has been tested; It works! Hope this helped!